# HP ALM REST API Getting audits based on time

Tags: rest, hp-alm

I want to fetch test-instance **HISTORY** records from a particular date. As per my knowledge, the audit query makes parent-id and parent-type mandatory fields to be supplied while querying for audit records. But in case of my scenario, I will not be aware of the IDs which were modified (records where last-modified date is not changed but only audit record is created), I won't have ID to be supplied in query string. Therefore, I want to query history records of a particular entity based on its time field.

Is it possible? Please post query if it is.

I am using ALM version 11.52 and ALM 12.

Answer (score 0):

Following query allows you to query based on audit time(not modified time) and without specifying ids of test-instance object.

```
?query={parent-type[test-instance];parent-id[<>-1];time[>='QUALIFIED_TIMESTAMP'and<='QUALIFIED_TIMESTAMP']}&order-by={time[ASC]}
```

Comment: specifying parent-id[<>-1] will be applicable on all the objects.